# How should attributes be eager loaded?

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a set of attributes/accessors on my model that are working out the number of flights for a specific aircraft type. Is there a way to only return these when I want them? If I add them to `appends[]` I get an `N+1` problem when loading all the resources.

```php
        /**
         *    Gets the number of flights flown by the aircraft
         */
        public function getTotalFlightsAttribute () {

            return Flight::whereHas('aircraft', function($query) {

                $query->where('aircraft_type_id', '=', $this->id);
            })
                         ->count();
        }
```

I'd like to be able to call `$aircraftType->load('total_flights')` when I'm serializing this model to send to Vue to like I can with relationships. Am I missing something here? I've tried to call the `getAttributes` method on the instance, which gets the value, but *only* the value. I want to simply include it like I can with relationships.

`<total-flights :data-aircraft-type="{{ $aircraftType->getAttribute('total_flights') }}"></total-flights>`

Ideally, I'm looking for a `withAttributes` method.

Comment: Show your Vue logic and you want to send `$aircraftType` object right?

Comment: Why is the Vue logic important? And yep, I'm trying to access `aircraftType.total_flights` from js.

Comment: Why use an accessor function for this, and not a relationship?

Comment: Would it be better suited to a relationship? I'm essentially trying to get all flights of all aircraft that are of this type, which sounds like a many-many relationship. Is there a way to define this on the `AircraftType` model without a pivot table?

Comment: @AlexGodbehere I don't know your exact data structure, but something like `public function flights() { return $this->hasMany('App\Flight', 'aircraft_type_id'); }` would let you do something like `AircraftType::withCount('flights')`.

Comment: @ceejayoz, unfortunately, I don't have an `aircraft_type_id` on my flight model. It goes `flight` -> `aircraft` -> `aircraft_type`. Is there still a way to do this?

Comment: @AlexGodbehere Look up `hasManyThrough` in the Eloquent relationship docs.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your problem, I guess this should do the job :

```
$aircraft_flights = $aircraft->total_flights;
```

Supposing $aircraft is an instance of Aircraft

Comment: Correct, this will work on its own, but I want to send the `$aircraft` object to the Vue instance *with* the `total_flights` included so that I can call `aircraft.total_flights` from my javascript.

Comment: How do you send your object to the Vue instance currently ?

Comment: `<total-flights :data-aircraft-type="{{ $aircraftType }}"></total-flights>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship from Flight to Aircraft, you should have the inverse from Aircraft to Flight. With that relationship setup you can get the relationship count:

```
$aircrafts = Aircraft::withCount('flights')->......->get();
```

Then you can remove that accessor from `appends` as these Aircraft models retrieved will have a `flights_count` attribute.