# Is there a way to cache variables in Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm passing a variable to my view from my controller using the `compact` function, which is then accessible in my view. However, each time that I access this variable, Laravel is making more and more calls to the database.

```php
return view('dashboard.overview', compact('aircraft', 'current_location', 'current_flight'));
```

Then in my Blade, I'm calling a Vue component like this: `<badge--aircraft--financed :data-aircraft="{{ $aircraft }}"></badge--aircraft--financed>`, which results in 10 queries. If i duplicate this line, `Debugbar` is showing that I make 20 queries, 10 of which are repeated. Does Blade not cache the `$aircraft` variable by default?

Comment: What does `aircraft` have anyway?

Comment: are you appending data with the `$appends` property of the Aircraft model? or have any accessors?

Comment: Yes, I have lots of accessors defined with `$appends`, but I'm trying to find a way to load these selectively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954629/how-should-attributes-be-eager-loaded). Is this the problem?

Comment: if they are touching relationship methods or dynamic properties for the relationship that aren't loaded, yes ... they will cause queries every time the accessor is used if that is the case .. you are literally doing a query in your accessor

Comment: Hmm, ok. Is there a way to pre-load accessors when required, other than adding them to the `appends` array?

Comment: answered your other question

Answer (score 3):

Laravel caches only blade templates, not variables.
You can cache your variable in controller
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/cache#cache-usage

Also, to prevent a lot of queries, you can call `with()` method when fetching $aircraft models.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks, but `with()` only works for relationships, not attributes, which seem to be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't because of any caching. Your models are getting serialized because of the `__toString` which is `toJson`. This takes into account the accessors you have defined to append to the data in `$appends`. You have accessors that are doing database queries. If you have 10 accessors and you are doing queries in them then for every Aircraft model you serialize you will have generated 10 queries.

You should look to avoid this, check if relationships are loaded and use the loaded relationship instead of generating a new query and try to eager load as much as possible.

Comment: Great, thanks. So if I have a relationship on the $aircraft model called flights(), would I use a scope to get the current flight? Currently I check for arrival_time, and if this is null return the first record. Would accessing the relationship from the attribute ($this->flights()) not make additional queries?